# laravel echo as a single js for non nodejs user

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install

as per https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/broadcasting laravel provides a wrapper for pusher they do it by there laravel-echo java script file code is:

```
import Echo from "laravel-echo"

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'your-pusher-key'
});
```

as far as i know this code is for node js but on my shared hosting I can't use nodejs

so how can i get the code from laravel-echo to a separate js for from end user on browser.

laravel echo provide a proper wrapper for private connection and also authentication.

all i can find that is http://browserify.org/ which helps in  bundling up all of your dependencies. (not sure i am a not a node js user).

but still i can't get a single java script file for a front end user on browser without nodejs.